# Selecting a dropdown option with no attributes with WATIR

Tags: watir

I am having trouble selecting this with watir. I'm trying xpath and is able to try something like this

```
browser.element_by_xpath("select/option[2]").text
```

and it will return the text. but how would i select the text in the dropdown. Thanks

```
 <select>
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="test">NAME1</option>
    <option value="test2">NAME2</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it myself. Here is what i did for reference.

```
      browser.select_list(:xpath, "select/option[2]").set(browser.select_list(:xpath, "select/option[2]").getAllContents[2])
```